# Microservicess with Serverless (Lambda or Function)

Tags: azure, lambda, microservices, azure-functions

I have some concern on getting an idea of migrating current microservices system into serverless.

Right now, between services are communicating with HTTP or API based.
Serverless like lambda or function can talk to each other with function call or lambda call. This way can be done by changing all HTTP code into lambda call within all services.

Another way is still using HTTP request to call another service that on lambda through API Gateway. This method of calling is not good because the service request gone to Internet and go back again into API Gateway then neighbor service get the request. Too long and does not make sense for me.

I will be glad if lambda app call another lambda app with local network HTTP request, this is still on my research on how to do it.

I would like to know from all of you about your experience on migrating microservices based on HTTP communication between services into serverless like Lambda or Functions ?

Do you change all your code into specific lambda function call ?
Do you use HTTP over internet and API Gateway again to call neighbor service ?
Have you guys figured it out on Local / Private network lambda call ?

Thank You

Answer (score 3):

Am I correct that you're talking about the orchestration of your microservices/functions?

If so have you looked at [AWS Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/) or [Durable Functions on Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable-functions-overview)?

### AWS Step Functions

> AWS Step Functions lets you coordinate multiple AWS services into serverless workflows so you can build and update apps quickly. Using Step Functions, you can design and run workflows that stitch together services such as AWS Lambda and Amazon ECS into feature-rich applications. Workflows are made up of a series of steps, with the output of one step acting as input into the next. Application development is simpler and more intuitive using Step Functions, because it translates your workflow into a state machine diagram that is easy to understand, easy to explain to others, and easy to change. You can monitor each step of execution as it happens, which means you can identify and fix problems quickly. Step Functions automatically triggers and tracks each step, and retries when there are errors, so your application executes in order and as expected.

Source: https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/

### Azure Durable Functions

> The primary use case for Durable Functions is simplifying complex, stateful coordination problems in serverless applications. The following sections describe some typical application patterns that can benefit from Durable Functions: Function Chaining, Fan-out/Fan-in, Async HTTP APIs, Monitoring.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable-functions-overview

Comment: Thank you for your input. Yes, I was talking about translating flow of my old implementation of Microservices that talked each other using local HTTP request to lambda or serverless style that currently not support local HTTP request on any cloud. On your input above, you are saying about migrating to something called like app logic on Azure right ? designing using logical flow or steps sounds like moving into the monolith design again, am I right ? I am still learning about mindset of serverless entirely.

Comment: @AdityoSetyonugroho I'm suggesting to look at Durable Functions, which are function orchestrations you define yourself in code (not a visual designer such as Logic Apps). Durable Functions uses storage queues and tables under the hood to orchestrate the flow and state between so-called Activity Functions. I would advise you to create relatively small orchestrations (related to one business context) to prevent creating monoliths like you mentioned.

Comment: Alright, I see. I think I remember something about this Durable Function. This kind of idea look the same like what Juan from Microsoft did in https://github.com/liarjo/MediaBlutlerTest01 . He is using table storage to define workflow. I will look at Durable Function. Nice, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You should consider communicating using queues. When one function finishes, it puts the results into the Azure Storage Queue, which is picked up by another function. Therefore there is no direct communication between functions unless it's necessary to trigger the other function.

In other words, it may look like this

> function1 ==> queue1 <== function2 ==> queue2 <== function 3 ==> somewhere else, e.g. storage

Comment: Thank you for your input. I will try to look at it and how possible with current implementation.